# How to run "poetry shell" in a shell script?

Tags: linux, python-poetry

I work with Python Poetry and need to automate the process. Specifically, everytime I need to go to a directory with

```sh
cd /work/directory
```

And spawn a poetry shell with

```sh
poetry shell
```

and again go to another directory

```sh
cd /other/directory
```

to finish the work.

I would love to automate this with a small script like

```sh
#!/bin/bash

cd /work/directory
poetry shell
cd /other/directory
# do work
```

However whenever I run this script, I get stucks at `poetry shell`. Is there any option like bash's `-c` so that I can do following?

```sh
poetry shell -c "cd /other/directory && do work"
```

Comment: did you ever figure this out? Please share your answer!

Comment: @Dobler no, sorry

Comment: How about something like ```export POETRY_ENV=`poetry env info -p`/bin/activate && . ${POETRY_ENV} && ls```?

Answer (score 14):

Probably you want to run a python script using the poetry virtual environment.
In that case, I think you should be using simple the command

```sh
poetry run {your_command}
```

For a more practical example you can run a python script as follows

```sh
poetry run python myscript.py
```

which will use the `poetry` virtual environment you already created with `poetry install`.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure what running `poetry shell` exactly entails.  Activating the virtual environment might be sufficient for your needs.
And if what you want to do is not interactive work on the command line, then activating the environment might not even be necessary.

Typically you would first need to identify the path to the virtual environment with something like `poetry env info --path`. Once you know that you can "activate it" from anywhere:

```
source /path/to/venv/bin/activate
```

Or (in most cases) you can just use any of the executables from that virtual environment directly without having to activate first:

```
/path/to/venv/bin/python path/to/script.py
```

Answer (score 2):

## Remix from other answers.

`poetry shell` spawns an environment, but we can also create an environment manualy using the `env use` command.

```sh
# This will create a Python3.7 env 

poetry env use 3.7
```

Why use `env use` vs `shell`?

`env use` is a pure method that has an output and ends the process. It also activates the environment as required.

So after `env` completes we can actually use @DaveR's answer and use the `run` command.

A chained version of this `my_bash_script.sh` script would be:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Activate / Create + activate my enviroment
poetry env use 3.7

# Run my script in the above environment
poetry run python3.7 my_script.py
```

## Extra

`env` command is helpful to see what envs you have activated.

```sh
poetry env list
```

Answer (score 2):

For some weird reason, I needed to activate an env in a project, then move to another folder and execute some script from there, all in a script. Thanks to [Zain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68732184/3921746), I made a simple one-liner to activate said env in the current shell.

```bash
source $(cd ~/path/to/project ; poetry env info --path)/bin/activate
```

Comment: This should be the solution; the documentation for poetry proposes a very similar [one-liner approach](https://python-poetry.org/docs/basic-usage/#activating-the-virtual-environment).